# Change the URL of landing page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This it might be easy but I'm not sure how to achieve it

I have site as www.example.com and this is my landing page. But my landing page should be www.example.com/home. but I don't want to show it as www.example.com/home in URL, I want it as www.example.com.

I want to do it using .htaccess.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ home [L]
```